# update the model by an Ajax call - Spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

please i insert data by ajax to my database in a page where i also have a table of records I inserted and in each time i add a data i want to update the content of the table. this is what i did :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add_record",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addUser(@ModelAttribute User us,BindingResult result,ModelMap model){
    userservice.AddUser(us);
    model.addAttribute("usersystem", userservice.getAllUsers()); // <== Here the problem
    return returnText = "you succefully add a record !" ;
}
```

The Jquery function ;

```
function doAjaxPost() {
    var frm = $('#ajf');
    frm.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajouter_user",
            data:  frm.serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                // we have the response
                $('#info').html(response);
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I don't know how can I return the attribute added by the controller to my jsp page, so i have always to refresh the page to see the new record.
Thank you

---

what if i use this way :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add_record",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute User us,BindingResult result,ModelMap model){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("jspName");
    userservice.AddUser(us);
    model.addObject("usersystem", userservice.getAllUsers()); // <== Here the problem
    return model;
}
```

can i receive this model in the ajax call ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be returning the data you want as the `@ResponseBody` or a `ResponseEntity` rather than adding it to a Model. Jackson (or whatever) should serialize it automatically to JSON so that it can be consumed in your success/done callback on the front end. AJAX requests are effectively service endpoints rather than MVC flows.

Comment: can you give me an example ? the problem I don't want to just return the attribute but also give its a name to be used in the jsp. above in the controller the name of the attribute is "usersystem".

Comment: You won't have access to it in JSP without doing a full request or if you did some solution where you're rending a partial view which you're retrieving and loading into the existing page.  If you want to do it with AJAX you're left with client side code which means JavaScript.  If you wanted to give it a "name" you could always return a Map<String, ...> and get the name that way, but it seems like that would pollute the API.  Additionally you could create a Model and try to serialize that or extract the Map out of it...but that's also using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: That may possibly work but would be horrifically ugly if it did.  If you want to process it through JSP then you can treat it just like any other MVC request (don't use `@ResponseBody`) and the response will be the rendered output (HTML).  If you want to do it the proper AJAX way you should be returning the data itself.  If you're looking for a quick fix then going through a server side View wouldn't be that bad...if you're looking to design a modern web app you should get used to the second way.

Comment: if i use the first way, then how i can call the attribut added in the controller into my jsp ??

Comment: The same way you would any other MVC request.  You'd have to treat it as a different page.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/add_record",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addUser(@ModelAttribute User us, BindingResult result, Model model){
             userservice.AddUser(us);
             model.addAttribute("usersystem", userservice.getAllUsers());
             model.addAttribute("msg", "you succefully added a record !");
             return "YourPageName :: #info"; // this only returns the info part of your page.
        }
```

Comment: doing this results in `jsp/mypage :: #mypageForm.jsp. Reason: Not Found` - where mypage.jsp contains an id mypageForm.

Comment: @DennisIch `jsp/mypage :: #mypageForm`